# MySQL Stored Procedure to order a linked list

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, data-structures, linked-list

I have a table with a representation of a linked list

```
id | parent
1  | 1
2  | 1
3  | 2
4  | 3
...
```

I know for a fact that mysql does not have the tree building capabilities built in for queries but I was wondering if anyone had used stored procedures to perform this sorting. Currently I am performing the sorting in my domain code but the table as to be read by an external system and performance is paramount on the external system so I would like to provide it with an already sorted list to not use its the precious CPU cycles.

Other advices are welcomed as this is still in the design phase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL doesn't have the handy `START WITH / CONNECT BY` syntax that Oracle does, however, you might want to check out [this link](http://explainextended.com/2009/03/17/hierarchical-queries-in-mysql/) from someone who tried to mimic this same functionality in MySQL.

Comment: I've used this [link](http://explainextended.com/2009/07/20/hierarchical-data-in-mysql-parents-and-children-in-one-query/) for hierarchical queries before and it works well. It's from the same site and I prefer his approach over the stored-proc/temp table approaches I've seen. He actually gives a fairly simple query to get the tree-hierarchy when given a leaf (the other way around root->leaves is a bit more complicated)

Answer (score 1):

I already solved this in the DBA StackExchange on October 24, 2011 : https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7147/find-highest-level-of-a-hierarchical-field-with-vs-without-ctes/7161#7161

In my answer, I included the stored procedures and sample data based on that question.

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: Thank you for the link. I have a question, the list starts with 0 where mine starts with 1 = 1 for the root. The reason for this is if you use 0 you cannot use the foreign key on the column where when you have for the root the parent equal to itself. What is your opinion on this ?